# How can i show all taxonomies of WP for categories and tags only?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying here with this code,

```
$all_terms = get_object_taxonomies(get_post_types(array('public'   => true ), 'names', 'and' ));
```

but it is rendering the `post_format`, other types like `product_visibility` too, but I want only tags and categories, is there any function or process that i can get only tags and categories

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) check the below code.

> For Tag.

```
$post_tag = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

> For category.

```
$category = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```